# Maximum Possible Number of Floating Point Units in Recent FPGAs

Tags: floating-point, fpga

I am not practicing FPGA implementation at this moment so please accept my appology if my question is naive. I am doing a feasibility study for a FPGA-based implementation of a numerical algorithm. I want to have many "floating point adder and multiplier" units and a light interface to orchestrate them to perform a matrix-vector product. Now considering the floating point unit implemented in (http://opencores.org/project,fpuvhdl), my question is, how many of these can I program on the recently manufactured FPGAs? I remember years ago, a couple of them were enough to fill an old Spartan FPGA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Xilinx has a floating point operator included in their IP catalog.

http://www.xilinx.com/products/intellectual-property/FLOATING_PT.htm

In the right hand column there is a resource utilzation link that provide a spreadsheet to calculate the resources used by various FP operator configurations.

The Kintex 7 product selection guide lists the resources available in their current mid range FPGA family.

http://www.xilinx.com/publications/prod_mktg/Kintex7-Product-Table.pdf

Between these you should be able to estimate how many you can program on a current production FPGA.  I think you will be pleasantly surprised at the increase over what you saw on the older Spartan.  The biggest difference is the Xilinx IP is using hardened 48bit DSP slices for much of the heavy lifting while the opencores design uses generic lut and flip flop resources.

That said a Kintex7 160 is listed as having 25350 slices.  Per the [7 series CLB user guide](http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/user_guides/ug474_7Series_CLB.pdf) there are 2 slices per CLB or 12675 CLBs.  Based on the opencores 119CLB / multiplier 106 multipliers would completely fill this mid to low end Kintex 7.  But in that same part there are also **600 DSP slices**.

Comment: thanks for reply the open core I mentioned has 385 CLBs for adder and 119 CLBS for multiplier which is roughly 500 logic blocks. Now the question is how many configurable logic blocks can be accessed on new FPGAs (typically)?

Comment: IF you use DSP48, the number of CLBs will be lower.

Comment: CLBs is not a constant unit across FPGA architectures.  Logic that consumes X CLBs in an older architecture/family could consume less in a more recent FPGA architecture.  It is far better (but not perfect) to estimate in terms of luts and flip flops.